# How to open command prompt from my application @Client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-prompt

Please help me how to open command prompt from client side. When i click on the button it should open command prompt. I tried in my PC and it's working in the development environment but when deploy in IIS its not opening.

Code:

```
    var Processstartinfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {           
        FileName = "cmd"
    };
    Process process = Process.Start(Processstartinfo);
```

Comment: This is server side code .. so it would open this on the server

Comment: You want someone to visit your website and for a cmd.exe window to appear?  What are your reasons behind wanting this?  Do you understand that if browser vendors permitted this then it would be absurdly easy to take over your computer and steal everything on your disk.

Comment: Actually in my application automatic shell scripting batch files will run @background.. So if any User want to recheck with those commands those can trace the commands by opening Command propmt thats why we need to open

Answer (score 5):

asp.net runs at the server. I suspect you are running in cassini locally, so your server desktop and client desktop are the same thing. What you are doing is opening a command prompt ***at the server***; which is an interesting DDOS attack surface if you think about it (i.e. don't do that).

Short answer: you **cannot do this**. No browser would (or should... I'll make allowances for IE ;p) allow this. The client OS need not even *support* a command prompt, nor .NET; and even if it did, very few browsers will let you spawn a process.

Comment: @santhosh if you "need" to do something that you ***should not be doing*** from a browser, then you made a poor design choice back up the road. A browser ***cannot reliably do this***. There are a few hacks **for IE only** I can think of, but that is layering on *a second* poor design decision. If you need a command prompt at the client, you should be writing a desktop application, not a browser app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a fake command prompt to be able to do this. As Marc said, it introduces a huge security risk and I would never to it.

To solve it you need to redirect standard input/output so that you can read/write to them. [Here is an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/edwinlima/SystemDiagnosticProcess12052005035444AM/SystemDiagnosticProcess.aspx). Create the command process and save the `Process` object in a session variable.

At client side add a `<div id="commandOutput"></div>` and `<input type="text" name="command" /><input type="submit" value="Execute command" />`. Use jquery or similar to hook the button click event.

Use ajax to submit the form. Execute the command by writing it to the `stdin` in the  `Process` object that is saved in the session variable. Read from standard out and return the result to the client which adds it to `commandOutput` div using jQuery or something else.

That should do it. Do note that anyone with access can do ***anything*** with your server.

Comment: it is an answer, but (as you note) *so* dangerous. Also, it doesn't really work very well against a farm. RPD over VPN is so preferred here...